# Get id of element on Mouseover in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, onmouseover

Firstly I know this question has very simple answer but first understand my problem.
This is my html and script.

```
<img onmouseover="FacebookprofileTip(1, 0)" onmouseout="FacebookprofileTip(0, 1);" onclick="FacebookprofileTip(0, 1);" id="imgProfile" src="#" />
<div class="row"  id="profile-tip"></div>
```

Script :

```
function FacebookprofileTip(post, delay) {
    //How do I get element id here
    //Non-relevant code
}
```

As per my requirement I want to get the id of "img" tag `onmouseover` event. but already I am passing 2 arguments to function for `post` and `delay` time to display tooltip message. So please tell me how can I get id in jquery.

Comment: You are passing number in the function `FacebookprofileTip(1, 0)` so you must be getting error in line `var j = $(g.target);` __What is your exact problem?__

Comment: My problem is how can i get id of img tag onmouseover with passing like FacebookprofileTip(1, 0) . Sorryyy.. see again updated code..

Comment: `// Set the position of the profile card
            $('#profile-tip').css(pos);`  can you explain this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its has very simple solution, pass the `this` reference to element which invoke the event to event handler. Then you can read `id` property.

```
<img onmouseover="FacebookprofileTip(1, 0, this)"  id="imgProfile" src="#" />
```

Change function as

```
function FacebookprofileTip(post, delay, elem) {
     alert(elem.id)
     //Rest of your code, now you can play with elem as required
}
```

```js
function FacebookprofileTip(post, delay, elem) {
  alert(elem.id)
}
```

```html
<img onmouseover="FacebookprofileTip(1, 0, this)" id="imgProfile" src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-qQRcAKHdBzE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAABE/sTjOPZrtj1g/photo.jpg?sz=32" />
```

Comment: yesss... you r the boss... you solved my problem... requesting to god to get knwoledge like you...